# Nodejs it is necessary to restart the application when we catch an unexpected / unknown error?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, shutdown

This is my function in typescript, when i catch error and he is unexpected/unknown how i handle this,
need restart app?

```
export const getUserById = async (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        const user = await userModel.findById(request.params.id);

    // NotfoundError extends appError extends Error.
    // first param message as string
    // second param isOperational as boolean
    if (!user) throw (new NotFoundError("user not found", true))
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
      // error is NotFoundError
    }

    error
    // here error is unexpected/unknown error
    // We need restart app for this error?
    // How handle this error?       
  }
}
```

Comment: you can just send the error in resposne ?

Comment: yes. But i dont need to restart the app for unexpected / unknown error?

Comment: No, why would you do that, instead log those exceptions on console or in a file,so user is aware what has went wrong

Comment: Because I thought that detect an unexpected / unknown error does corrupted the application state

Comment: HAVE A LOOK AT THIS, https://javascript.info/try-catch

Comment: thanks I have already read it.
So from what I have read and weres have told me I understand that all unexpected/unknown errors are operational and not programmatic.